# Updating database and calling stored procedure in same method, but doesn't seem to be in the same session

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

We're using Java 8, Hibernate, JPA, WebLogic and Oracle DB.

We're writing a record into a table and then getting back the primary key. We then pass that primary key to a stored procedure so that it can process the record. The problem is that it seems that the two are in separate sessions because without committing the database insertion, the stored procedure doesn't seem to be able to see the new record.

This would not be an issue if nothing bad ever happened, but the stored procedure is failing in certain circumstances. This means that the effects of the stored procedure get rolled back, but the committed insertion (obviously) does not get rolled back.

Can anyone give any hints or best practices on making the commit and then the stored procedure call work nicely with each other? How can we get the stored procedure to see the new record without issuing a commit?